# How do I import HTML files to be displayed in a VB.NET WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net

So far I've gotten this from piecing together OpenDialog tutorials and HTML editor/writer tutorials but I just picked this up today, to do this specific thing so my prior knowledge of VB and general software development is EXTREMELY low. :P

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1 Click

   OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
   If OpenFileDialog1.FileName > "" Then
   WebBrowser1.DocumentText = 

End sub
```

Comment: Where are you importing the html from?

Comment: From my computers local storage specifically Folders on my desktop

Comment: This might help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-text-files

Answer (score 0):

Use URL propery of WebBrowser Control   also always use filter to select desired format only

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

            OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Html or Pdf-Files(*.html; *.pdf))|*.html;*.pdf"
            If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim cfilenam As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName()
                If cfilenam.Trim().Length > 0 Then
                    Me.WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri(cfilenam)
                    Me.WebBrowser1.Refresh()
                End If
            End If

        End Sub
```